# jquery AnythingSlider control

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I need to have a external link as a navigation to next and prev slide.

I thougt that the "appendForwardTo" would work but I quess that I´m doing something wrong...

```
$('.quiz-items a').click().goForward()
```

But just get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'goForward'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to do something similar to this

```
$('.quiz-items a').click(function(){
    $('#slider1').data('AnythingSlider').goForward(); 
});
```

Comment: @Mackelito Click on the button left to an answer to accept it. You have done it to 50% of your questions. My guess would be that there are more correct answers out there <(

Comment: oooooh hehe.. that!.. ok I´ll go thru my questions! :)  .....
Ok so something is happening when I do it your way. the background color of the panels changes.. but that´s it :P hmm.. I´ll keep on trying! :)

Comment: Ok, well thats what the documentation says. Can you provide a jsfiddle example_

Comment: The code is a real mess and can´t even get it to work properly in jsfiddle for debugging... :/

Comment: Now I found it.. it was broken HTML that caused the issue.. your code worked just fine! ;)